# RN Firebase default firebase app hasn't be initialized

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I can't connect my RN app to firebase using react-native-firebase library.

Here is a quote from library docs:

*The default app is pre-initialized natively therefore there is no need to call initializeApp for the default app instance.*

However, app throw this mistake:

```
    The [[DEFAULT]] firebase app has not been initialized!
    app
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\react-native- 
    firebase\dist\utils\apps.js:36:30
    getModule
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\react-native- 
    firebase\dist\utils\apps.js:185:24
    <unknown>
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\src\screen_editTest.js:15:12
    loadModuleImplementation
 C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:320:6
guardedLoadModule

 C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:214:36
metroRequire
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:136:24
<unknown>
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\App.js:138
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:320:6
guardedLoadModule
    C:\Users\yuriy\Desktop\recipe\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:214:36
metroRequire
```

Comment: There are a few things that could causing this error. Check if you have installed firebase properly (linking, check if you have you added the json file from the firebase console, check if package name from firebase console is matching with your package name locally)